# Missing Organization Feature: NetworksEnabledOnce

Tags: community, managed-package, package-install

I'm having the following error message when I'm trying to install a package

Missing Organization Feature: NetworksEnabledOnce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this error is necessary to have communities enable first

Setup -> Communities -> All Communities

Comment: For info Salesforce updated this a while back, it is now 
Setup -> Digital Experiences